# Server is able to receive mail, but mail it sends never get to destination?

Tags: mx-record, txt-record, mac-osx-server

I have a OS X Server behind a router.
Server's ip address is 10.0.1.3.
The router has open ports on everything and an external ip.

I've setup my mail exchange. I can receive mail people send to me but the reply never gets back to them.

I don't use TXT records, could that be the problem? Could my ISP be blocking something?

Comment: Have you looked at /var/log/mail.log on your server?

Answer (score 0):

- Check your [FCrDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS) to ensure you aren't getting binned as spam. You should also confirm how your server identifies itself to the outside world by telnetting to port 25 on your server and checking the banner.
- Further to spam issues, run your IP through [MultiRBL](http://multirbl.valli.org/)
- Ensure you can telnet from your server to a known-good remote mailserver on port 25 (e.g. `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com`).
- What do your mail logs say? These should be in `/var/log/maillog` (or mail.log).

Comment: telnet: connect to address 5.x.x.x: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host I'm able to connect to apache http server just fine. I think my ISP is blocking port 25!